# Open Qt MainWindow on top of every other window in single instance Qt application version 5.11.1 in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

I have made single instance running Qt application (Qt version 5.11.1) in **Visual Studio**. Once it executed the first time, my main window will open and I am closing it. It keeps running in the background.

When I run .exe the second time, I want to open the previous mainWindow which I opened the first time.

I am enumerating available windows title and I am getting **"Test Window"** title. but using this **HWND** I am trying to set in the foreground on top of every other window using `SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);`.

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd)) // check whether window is visible
    {
        char wnd_title[256];
        GetWindowText(hwnd, wnd_title, sizeof(wnd_title));
        MessageBox(0, wnd_title, "Installation Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        if (strcmp(wnd_title, "Test Window") == 0)      
        {

            SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);

            int err = GetLastError();
            string msg = "error code " + std::to_string(err);
            MessageBox(0, msg.c_str(),"Installation Error ",  MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; // function must return true if you want to continue enumeration
}
```

How do I open on **Qt MainWindow** on top of all other windows when I run second time.

Answer (score 1):

check out the project QtSingleApplication found in https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions.

In QtSingleApplication class there is a method named **activateWindow**. In the **Loader** Example this method gets called whenever a second instance of the program is run.

To make the main window go on top when you try to open a second instance you've got to modify this method like this.

```
void QtSingleApplication::activateWindow()
{
    if (actWin) {
        actWin->setWindowState(actWin->windowState() & ~Qt::WindowMinimized);
        actWin->activateWindow();
        actWin->raise();
        //winapi call
        SetWindowPos((HWND)actWin->winId() , HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
       //hack to prevent sticking window to the fore
       SetWindowPos((HWND)actWin->winId() , HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
    }
}
```

Warning: this is a windows-only solution and it works on my machine. Be also sure to include **windows.h** in the implementation.

[edit] My code had the problem that once activated, window stayed to the fore. This hack sort of fixes it.

Comment: I am using qt version 5.11.1. In this version they removed this QtSingleApplication

Comment: You can get it from the site I provided. git-clone the project, try to run the **loader** app and implement the modifications. I tested it on 5.11.1

Comment: This does not make the window the foreground window, which is apparently what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: To my understanding, what Narendra wants is that when the app icon is clicked, if this is running, its window comes to fore, and this is what my edited version of **Loader** does. My machine is a Win10, with Qt 5.11.1

Comment: You need to understand, what [foreground and background windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#foreground-and-background-windows) are. Your proposed solution brings a window to the front (sort of), but doesn't make it the foreground window. People do use keyboards; do not assume that mouse activation were the only type of activation (although with Qt being as broken as it is, it certainly looks like it were).